# How can I create a class without defining it in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a class at server-side like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public Address(string countryCode)
    {
        this._CountryCode = countryCode;
    }

    private string _CountryCode = string.Empty;
    public string CountryCode
    {
        get { return _CountryCode; }
        set { _CountryCode = value; }
    }

}
```

and I have a method that called by Ajax methods :

```
[AjaxMethod]
public static Address ValidateAddress(Address address)
{
   // Some logic here...
   return address;
}
```

And I want to call this method in client side, but how can I instantiate the Address class in client side? I do not want to define a class named `Address` in JavaScript file.

```
<script>

function valaddress(){ 

  var address = new Address(); // I'm asking here ??
  address.CountryCode = 90;

  // This part is ok, no problem in here : 
  var validatedAddress = AddressControlDataHelper.ValidateAddress(address).value; 

}

</script>
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to write my Address class in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var address = { 
    CountryCode: "1"
}
```

That should do the trick

```
<script>
  function valaddress(){ 

      var address = { 
          CountryCode: "90"
      };

      // This part is ok, no problem in here : 
      var validatedAddress = 
       AddressControlDataHelper.ValidateAddress(address).value; 

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to serialize the object first.  One way to do this is with [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (Javascript Object Notation) - <del>[here is a tutorial on how that works.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SerializingObjectsAsJavaScriptUsingAtlasJSONNETAndAjaxPro.aspx)</del> **EDIT:** (Actually that tutorial is quite confusing and a bit outdated - try [this one for a more direct, up-to-date approach.](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Using the .net AJAX extensions, you can add the GenerateScriptType tag above, for example, your server side ValidateAddress()

```
[GeneratScriptType(typeof(Address)]
```

The server would send the necessary js down to the client so you could make the js call

```
var address = new nameofyournamespace.Address()
```

See the  [msdn GenerateScriptTypeAttribute reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.generatescripttypeattribute.aspx)